# How to implement states on a windows form appliaction

Tags: c#

I am developing a c# windows form application. In my application i have 3 forms (main form that has a list box and two buttons (Check in and check out), check in form and the check out form). On the main form, the list box contain user names, if a user select their name for the first time, the check in button must be enabled for the user to check in... But if the user checks in and then closes the application, when they reopen it, the button check out should be enabled and check in disabled.

I have been told to use the application/user states, but since I'm new in programming, i don't know how to implement the windows form states.

What should i do?

Thank you

Comment: You mean application / user settings? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: An application state is usually defined as an enumeration that reflects the application's current mode.  If you are in a "New User" state, certain buttons may be disabled/enabled as opposed to a "Normal" state.  You can implement this as a class that is available to all of your forms.  This can be a static class that gets initialized when the application starts

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "Windows Forms states". You have several options to implement somthing like this, among which are:

1. Use a database (this makes sense if you have a varying number of users and a database server available)
2. Use user settings (this is a builtin mechanism of the .NET framework, but may not be suitable for lots of users)
3. Use a simple XML file to store the states of all users.

All three solutions require you to sort of "get into things". Write more about what you have available (database server, etc.) or whether you want a fixed number of users and I can extend this answer to help you get started.

I'm going to line out how to do number 2:

Create a little helper class that assigns a state to a user name:

```
public class UserState
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool CheckedIn { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return String.Format("{0}={1}", UserName, CheckedIn); }
}
```

This class allows you to store a user name and the checked in state and by calling `ToString()` get a value in the form "user=false".

Then, create a user scoped application setting (go to settings-tab of project settings and add a new setting of type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`) named `UserStates`. You can access this setting from code as `Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates`. It is basically a list of strings.

To add and persist a new entry you could do this:

```
UserState state = new UserState() { UserName = "Test", CheckedIn = false };
Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates.Add(state.ToString());
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

The state for user "Test" (and the previously existing entries) are now stored across program restarts.

Now the idea is to build a list of users and their states when starting the program and to store this list when exiting.

Declare this as a member variable in the class:

```
private List<UserState> userStates = new List<UserState>();
```

Do the following in the form's `OnLoad` event:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates == null || Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates.Count == 0)
{
    // Add your users to the collection initially. This is the first
    // run of the application
    userStates.Add(new UserState() { ... });
    ...
}
else
{
    // Each line in the setting represents one user in the form name=state.
    // We split each line into the parts and add them to the internal list.
    for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates.Count; i++)
    {
        string stateLine = Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates[i];
        string[] parts = stateLine.Split('=');
        userStates.Add(new UserState() { UserName = parts[0].Trim(), CheckedIn = Boolean.Parse(parts[1].Trim()) });
    }
}
```

This creates a new entry in an internal list of users for each stored line in the collection setting.

When a button is clicked, change the state in the respective `UserState` object in the list.

Do the following in the form's `OnClose` event:

```
// Create the collection from scratch
Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

// Add all the users and states from our internal list
foreach (UserState state in userStates)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.UserStates.Add(state.ToString());
}

// Save the settings for next start
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

This persists the current list of user states to the setting.

Please note: I have tested this in Visual Studio now and it works. I leave the question of how to map the list box entries to the `UserState` objects in the internal list to you/as topic for a new question :-D

The downside of this approach: It is not very flexible - adding more states per user involves some coding.

It could be better for you to read about typed datasets and how to store/read them from XML. This gives you some sort of "database feeling" without actually having to use a database.